# How to receive HTML Post in console application?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm currently using MVC to fetch data from a HTML POST ajax call. I want to transform my web application to a console application.

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: '/Home/Final/',
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: JSON.stringify(response),
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  success: function () {
                      $('#messge').html('Response Saved').fadeIn();
                  },
                  error: function () {
                      $('#message').html('Error occured').fadeIn();
                  }
```

MVC code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Final(Something thing)
    {
        saveSomething(thing);
        return null;
    }
```

In other words, I currently call selenium to automatically fill some information on a website which then makes a POST call back to a MVC controller. Entity Framework works with or without MVC anyways.

I want to change my application to an .EXE so that I can call it periodically.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is that new .EXE only executed on each request or can it be always running?

Comment: Is this ajax call wrapped into any UI element, so that you can simulate the process "batchly" with Selenium ?

Comment: @Bsa0 I would run the .exe every 5mins to see if there a change and update values if needed

Comment: @Veverke I'm not sure how to answer your question. Selenium calls an HTML page. When that page is loaded, it posts back the information directly. There is no UI. I want 0 user interaction

Comment: Why you need the page to be loaded then ? If you simply perform a http get request to the given url, you will get the desired response ? In other words, if the reason you access the page is because it performs an ajax call you want to run, then you should not be performing this asynchronous get request from an html page, because there is no need for it, you can do it simply by making a get request, say, with your browser (or advanced REST client from google).

Comment: And how do know if there are any changes if there is no user interaction?

Comment: Unsure if I understood, but if it _seems_ you want to run an exe, optionally taking params that can be used to send an HTTP POST. If so, sure you can do that, just create a Console app that takes params. You can execute from command line (or schedule in Windows scheduler) e.g. `myconsoleapp.exe foo bar` where "foo" and "bar" are params that are used to construct your HTTP POST payload.

Answer (score 1):

read this post 

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

i hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Create a powershell script which invokes a web request to your controller by using Invoke-WebRequest function.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType application/json -Method POST -Uri https://yoururl
```

Then create a scheduled task in your web server and call that powershell script every 5 minutes

```
powershell -command "C:\Sample.ps1"
```